# How separate items in 2 columns in smartgwt menu?

Tags: menu, multiple-columns, smartgwt

I'm trying to organizate my menu (which has many `menuItem` added) in 2 columns, this way it will be better for smaller computer screen to see.

I'm using smartgwt menu and I am adding this way:

```
m_menu.setItems(
   m_itemSaude,          v_separator, m_itemMSeguranca,  v_separator,
   m_itemMeioAmbiente,   v_separator, m_itemTerceiros,   v_separator,
   m_itemInfra,          v_separator, m_itemProjetos,    v_separator,
   m_itemSegOperacional, v_separator, m_itemRH,          v_separator,
   m_itemQualidade,      v_separator, m_itemSuprimentos, v_separator,
   m_itemComunicacao,    v_separator, m_itemReceitasAlt, v_separator,
   m_itemAdmin);
```

Is there any way to organize in 2 columns these `menuItem`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that with only one MenuItem, maybe you can try using two.
The other option is going full custom and build your own widget from scratch, but thats going to be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could take some inspiration from this sample:
http://www.smartclient.com/#menuEmbeddedComponentsNewSample